# Android: Is there a way around SuperNotCalledException?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to override a class derived from Activity (called NativeActivity) so I can set my own content view created in Java while leaving the rest of its functionality in tact.  I must use NativeActivity, because it is the only way to get touchpad input on Xperia Play.  The method I need to override is the NativeActivity.onCreate() method, because that is where the content view that I don't want is being set.  The problem is, if I don't call super.onCreate() in my overridden onCreate() method, a SuperNotCalledException gets thrown.  This is coming from the Activity class.  But all the Activity.onCreate() method does is set a boolean:

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mVisibleFromClient = !mWindow
                    .getWindowStyle()
                    .getBoolean(
                            com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowNoDisplay,
                            false);
            mCalled = true;
        }
```

I can do that check in my own code, using the Activity.getWindow() method.  Unfortunately, the mCalled boolean is private, so I can't just set it to true in my own code.  I can't seem to figure out how to get around this requirement.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I figured out from studying the sourcecode for Activity, is you could call one of the methods that set mCalled to true in the base Activity clase, which are not overridden in the subclass, and which do nothing in the base Activity class.  So in the case of NativeActivty, one could call something like `super.onRestart();`, because this class is not overridden by NativeActivity, and as you can see below, it doesn't do anything in the Activity class:

```
protected void onRestart() {
    mCalled = true;
}
```

This is quite hackish, and could be broken at some future version, but can be a quick solution if you don't want to have to recreate an entire subclass of Activity just because of one simple boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `super.onCreate(savedInstance)` when you override this method on an Activity.

Digging through the code this check looks like it is intended to make sure that any custom Instrumentation works correctly.  And the requirement of calling super on some methods in all our custom Activities was an unintended consequence of the implementation.

Without getting into the details of *why* this is a bad OOP design, I can say that at least it's simple enough to just call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in your onCreate() method.  As you can see from the code, there are no bad side effects.

Comment: The bad side effect comes from the NativeActivity.onCreate() method.  In Java there is no super.super.  the point of overriding the method is that I don't want to call it.

Comment: @user1002212 I'm not sure if I understand you. Is it just a personal desire not to call super.onCreate()?

Comment: It's nothing personal, it is a requirement.  As described in my question above, my class extends NativeActivity, not Activity.  I want to avoid calling NativeActivity.onCreate (which will happen if I call super.onCreate), because in NativyActivity.onCreate it sets the content view (which I don't want to do).

Comment: @user1002212 - in that case, you probably don't want to inherit from NativeActivity at all; it is weird having class hierarchies where derived classes try to remove features a base class adds. Of course, the downside is that you have to duplicate all the stuff NativeActivity provides that you do want.

Comment: Thanks, that would work in most cases of subclasses of Activity, but for NativeActivity there is a native component as well.  In order to subclass Activity directly, I'd have to duplicate that component as well (which is more work than I was interested in).  I ended up solving my original problem differently, anyway, so I didn't need this after all.