# Another Unsatisfied Linker Error. Cannot find 'main'

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

I have tried to create an Android Native Activity by following the many guides out there, but I cannot get my application to run.  Instead, I am presented with the following from LogCat:

```
05-15 07:39:21.337 I/ActivityManager(  857): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.bigdavedev.opengl/.MainActivity} from pid 1450
05-15 07:39:21.377 D/dalvikvm(23970): Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-15 07:39:21.387 I/ActivityManager(  857): Start proc com.bigdavedev.opengl for activity com.bigdavedev.opengl/.MainActivity: pid=23970 uid=10221 gids={50221, 1028}
05-15 07:39:21.507 W/Adreno-EGL(  320): <qeglDrvAPI_eglMakeCurrent:2843>: EGL_BAD_MATCH
05-15 07:39:21.507 E/libEGL  (  320): eglMakeCurrent:671 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
05-15 07:39:21.517 I/ActivityManager(  857): Config changes=1480 {1.0 240mcc8mnc en_GB ldltr sw360dp w598dp h335dp 480dpi nrml land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.19 skinPackageSeq.1}
05-15 07:39:21.527 I/InputReader(  857): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
05-15 07:39:21.527 I/InputReader(  857): Device reconfigured: id=9, name='clearpad', size 1080x1920, orientation 1, mode 1, display id 0
05-15 07:39:21.577 D/dalvikvm(21541): GC_CONCURRENT freed 767K, 77% free 2600K/11244K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 32ms
05-15 07:39:21.607 D/QualcommSoftapCmd(  316): Got softap getStaList command we are passing on
05-15 07:39:21.607 D/SomcSoftapController(  316): Got info: dc:85:de:16:fc:89
05-15 07:39:21.627 D/AndroidRuntime(23970): Shutting down VM
05-15 07:39:21.627 W/dalvikvm(23970): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415828b0)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bigdavedev.opengl/com.bigdavedev.opengl.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find native library: main
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:172)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at com.bigdavedev.opengl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-15 07:39:21.627 E/AndroidRuntime(23970):     ... 11 more
05-15 07:39:21.627 W/ActivityManager(  857):   Force finishing activity com.bigdavedev.opengl/.MainActivity
```

I have read the following questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583917/unable-to-find-native-library-error-in-native-activity-app) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686900/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-unable-to-load-native-library) but none of this has helped me.  I paste below my futile efforts in the hope that someone can see what I cannot.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bigdavedev.opengl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hasCode="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bigdavedev.opengl.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib"
                android:value="@string/app_name" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainAcitivy.java:

```
package com.bigdavedev.opengl;

import android.app.NativeActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends NativeActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := bigdavedev
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp \
                   dave/application/application.cpp \
                   dave/core/kernel.cpp \
                   dave/platform/android.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2 

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module, android/native_app_glue)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-10

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8

APP_STL :=  gnustl_shared

APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

And, finally, main.cpp:

```
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>
#include "dave/application/application.hpp"

extern "C"
{

    void android_main(struct android_app* state)
    {
        app_dummy();

        dave::application app(state);

        if (app.initialise())
        {
            app.run();
        }
    }

}
```

At this point, I'm certain that I am staring right at the solution without even realising it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the meta-data tag need to look like:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.lib_name"
    android:value="@string/app_name" />
```

Everything works as it should now.